# how to run scripts in hook folder cordova?

Tags: cordova

I am trying to run scripts within the hook folder as described here; http://devgirl.org/2013/11/12/three-hooks-your-cordovaphonegap-project-needs/. I have created a cordova project and ran the cordova platform add (ios) command. Then I added two different scripts (one test.sh and one test.js). Here is the sh/bash one;

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "yo"
mkdir t
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
```

I then chmod a+x test.sh within the hooks folder, before going out to the root of the cordova project and wrote cordova prepare. Now I would expect to have a plugin added in my plugins folder, but it does not seem like the script has been executed. Is there something else I have to do to get it to work? The script works fine when explicitly using sh test.sh in the hooks folder. I found a related question, but this deals only with the .js-file not the bash/sh script ([cordova plugin installation issue when using node script in hooks folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24880197/cordova-plugin-installation-issue-when-using-node-script-in-hooks-folder?rq=1)). I found a second related question ([Cordova hooks, Get projects name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25354535/cordova-hooks-get-projects-name?rq=1))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some examples are given [in the Apache official example](https://github.com/apache/cordova-app-hello-world/blob/master/hooks/README.md).

You have to put them in one of the directories listed as **Supported hook types**, i.e. `after_platform_add` depending on your needs.

You may also write them directly within the `config.xml`, i.e. `<hook type="before_build" src="myScripts/myHook.js" />`

I would recommend to write them in JavaScript but you can obviously write them in Shell (`.sh`) or batch (`.bat`).