# No scripts found for hook "after_run". Cordova, Ionic, Android

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm building an Android application using Cordova, Ionic and Angular.  At some point the application has stopped running on the device.  When I run:

`ionic run android --verbose`

I get the splash screen on my tablet, but in the mac console I get:

after LAUNCH SUCCESS

No scripts found for hook "after_run".

and then on the device screen I get the dreaded Application Error:
The connection to the server was unsuccessful (file:///android_asset/www/index.html)

followed by the big crash..

I tried looking for the "after_run" string in the code, but I only find it in the documentation, so I have no idea what could be causing this.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try to add this line in your config.xml file: `<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />`

Comment: That worked! Am still getting 'No scripts found for hook "after_run".' but the app is no longer crashing.

Comment: In this regard maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30717581/how-to-run-scripts-in-hook-folder-cordova

Comment: `No scripts found for hook "after_run"` - this is just a verbose logging message, and not an error or warning. (it says that no hook scripts were found for this event)